# Alignment of Algorithm and Figure are not precise

Tags: alignment

Consider the following code:

```
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[style = Matlab-editor, caption = {MATLAB Algorithm 6}, label = first]
function [text] = TEXT(text,text)
a=text;
b=text;
T(:,1)=c;
s=b(w,y);
q=r+s;
plot(a,b,c,d,e,f)
end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\smallskip
  %\rule{0.3\textwidth}{50pt}
  \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{textimage.jpg}
  \captionof{figure}{textabcdefg} \label{myfig1}
\end{minipage}
```

[image]

The alignment between the figure and the algorithm is not feasible even though I attempted to change the ratio of scale/textwidth but the alignment still did not work

Comment: How do you want them to be aligned? By their top? centre? bottom?

Comment: I wish to have them aligned by the top @Bernard

Comment: And where did you find the `matlab-editor` style?

Comment: I used the package ```\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}``` @Bernard

Comment: You realize that your first `minipage` is missing the `[t]` option? If you add it, they will be properly aligned, however that means the caption of the left minipage will be aligned to the top line of the right minipage.

Comment: Tested with an  example-image: one obtains a nice alignment adding the option `[t]` to the first minipage, and replacing `\smallskip` with `vskip 4.8ex` (to be adjusted in function of your image, and the real code on the left).

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you @Bernard

Comment: and thank you @MarkusG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Bernard's comment: One obtains a nice alignment adding the option [t] to the first minipage, and replacing \smallskip with vskip 4.8ex (to be adjusted in function of your image, and the real code on the left).